# Exception Error on extension install: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am getting following message on my home page of megento site

```
There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1105843260151
```

Below is message in log file (.../var/report)

```
a:5:{i:0;s:363:"Error in file: "/home3/kenblack/public_html/egenieshop.com/app/code/local/Vilpjsc/Brand/sql/brand_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-2.0.4.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' DROP COLUMN `filename`' at line 2";i:1;s:1106:"#0 /home3/kenblack/public_html/egenieshop.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home3/kenblack/public_html/egenieshop.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.0.0', '2.0.4')
#2 /home3/kenblack/public_html/egenieshop.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.0.0', '2.0.4')
#3 /home3/kenblack/public_html/egenieshop.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home3/kenblack/public_html/egenieshop.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home3/kenblack/public_html/egenieshop.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home3/kenblack/public_html/egenieshop.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home3/kenblack/public_html/egenieshop.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I am getting this error during installing some extension.I don't know the extension name now.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this one - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shop-by-brand-manufacturer-free-extension.html

You can tell by the namespace used, `Vilpjsc_Brand`. Disable it by setting the `<active>` node to false in `app/etc/modules/Vilpjsc_Brand.xml`;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vilpjsc_Brand>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Vilpjsc_Brand>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Nice one - in an ideal world I'd have told you how to fix the module rather than just disable it.  You could just reinstall it manually, but an old free module like that thing....best remove it altogether, there are bound to be better ones than that available.  Cheers!